# How to do migration for the attribute type change (String to Int16) in Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm new iOS App Development.

I have CoreData named as ABC.sqlite with 20 versions of dataModel. I have created a new Model version 21 and make version data model as the current version.

In the version 21, I have created two new attributes and renamed an existing attribute name and type. I have already set the options `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` as true, to do the lightweight migration. Also, I have set the renaming identifier for the renamed attribute.

But the attribute type change wasn't eligible the lightWeight Migration.

So I have created a new Mapping Model as Custom `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` Class and mentioned the class in the Custom Policy (Right Pane inspector - under Entity Mapping). In the type Changed attribute, I have set the value expression as `FUNCTION($source.<attribute name here>, "intValue")`.

But I still get the error as `Error Reason: Source and destination attribute types are incompatible`.

I'm Stuck with this, Can anyone help me out, What I'm missing while performing Migration.
I need to do lightWeight migration, including the type change in an attribute.